# Frontend post submission editor how to add post format？

Tags: front-end, post-formats

[image]

Already have the following content, how should I add it?

```php
$cat =  esc_sql($_POST['cat']);
$post_status = 'pending';
if(_MBT('post_tougao_submit')){
    $post_status = 'publish';
}
$submit = array(
    'ID' => esc_sql($_POST['pid']),
    'post_title' => strip_tags($title),
    'post_author' => $current_user->ID,
    'post_content' => $content,
    'post_category' => array($cat),
    'post_status' => $post_status
);
$status = wp_update_post( $submit );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the post format using [`set_post_format()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_post_format/), which in your case, I would do it like so where I set the post format only if the post was successfully updated:

```php
$status = wp_update_post( $submit );

if ( $status && ! is_wp_error( $status ) ) {
    // Replace 'quote' with whatever the format you preferred.
    set_post_format( $status, 'quote' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.